# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'firstChild'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was trying to upgrade the code to have the array ordernum contain every single order number (separated by a separator, but that isn't really necessary I was just too lazy and I copy-pasted my own code).

Then the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'firstChild'` appeared when I added the last block of code. How do I fix this?

```
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

j=0
path = "C:/Users/User/Downloads"
quantity = []
# for every file in directory (path above)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename) # add path and file together
    data = parse(fullname) # parses XML
    ordernum = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderNumber') # gets OrderNumber from XML
    print(ordernum[0].firstChild.nodeValue) # prints OrderNumber from XML
    quan = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderedQuantity') # same as above with OrderedQuantity
    k=0
    l=0
    for k, q in enumerate(quan):
        if q.firstChild.nodeValue != None:
            quantity.append(quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue)
    quantity.append("||separator||")
    for l, p in enumerate(ordernum):
        if p.firstChild.nodeValue != None:
            ordernum.append(ordernum[l].firstChild.nodeValue)
    ordernum.append("||separator||")
```

XML Example:

```
<OrderNumber>8762196_W0169</OrderNumber>
<OrderedQuantity>2.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>4.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>6.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>3.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>1.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>8.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>6.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>7.000</OrderedQuantity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so in 2nd loop, you are trying to enumerate

`for l, p in enumerate(ordernum):`

and also inside loop you are appending an element to the same object i.e `ordernum`

So the object length is also increasing as you are populating inside the loop itself.

Try using another object/list for storing.